# Set all whitespaces in a log to a single space

Tags: powershell, scripting

Hi I have a file with logs, some fields of this logs are separated by space and others by a tab or two spaces, how can I set all whitespaces to just a single space using powershell?

something similar to awk in linux bash, beacuse I have one field tha contains staces in his value like this: "type:Windows Resources"

```
awk '{print "  $1 " " $2 " " $3 " " $5 " " $6 " " $7 " " $8 " " $9 " " $10}'
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below will replace only 2 or more spaces with single space.

```
((Get-Content logFile.txt) -replace '\s{2,}',' ') >> logFileTemp.txt;
Copy-Item logFileTemp.txt logFile.txt -Force
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, replace 1 or more whitespaces:

```
echo "hi   hi`t`thi" > file1.txt

cat file1.txt
hi   hi         hi

(cat file1.txt) -replace '\s+',' ' | set-content file2.txt

cat file2.txt
hi hi hi
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$test = "                                             Testing removal     of spaces"
$SpacesConverted = $test -replace "[ ]{1,1000}"," "
$SpacesConverted
```

**Output:** 
`Testing removal of spaces`

What I'm doing is replacing spaces, looking for any space between 1 and a 1000 and converting that to a single space. If you have more than 1000 spaces in any given part of the log just increase that number.

If you want to run this on a file...

```
$File = "c:\file123.txt"
gc $File -replace "[ ]{1,1000}"," " | sc $File
```